# How can a linkbutton embedded within a gridview check a embedded checkbox on the same row?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview with 4 visible columns, the first visible column contains a link button which evaluates an ID and the fourth visible column contains a checkbox.

Preferably with javascript I'd like to check the corresponding checkbox (same row) when the link button is clicked while unchecking all other checkboxes in the gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvSalesOrder" runat="server" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"
                            SelectedRowStyle-CssClass="alt-backcolour">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:CommandField Visible="false" ShowSelectButton="true" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ORDER NUMBER" ItemStyle-Width="31%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkOrderNumber" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CommandName="select"
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderNumber") %>' Text='<%# Eval("OrderNumber") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ACCOUNT REF" ItemStyle-Width="31%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerAccountReference" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerAccountReference") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QUOTED DUE DATE" ItemStyle-Width="31%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblQuotedDueDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuotedDueDate", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="6%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                        <input id="chkAll" type="checkbox" onclick="javascript:SelectAllCheckboxes(this);" />
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                No Sales Orders Found.
                            </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick`, and use the `CommandArgument` to pass in the item index:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click" CommandArgument='<%# Container.ItemIndex %>' OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chk = GridView1.Rows[(int)e.CommandArgument].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
        chk.Checked = true;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Grid_RowDataBound()` event handler, you can attach a client side onClick event on the button to check the checkbox.

In that method you have access to the button in the grid as well as the `chkSelect` checkbox's ClientID. You can either hard-code this or pass parameters to a JS function.

`lnkOrderNumber.OnClientClick = "CheckOnlyOne('"+chkSelect.ClientID+"');";`

and then JS:

```
function CheckOnlyOne(checkboxID)
{
    // TODO: uncheck all checkboxes
    document.getElementById(checkboxID).checked = true;
}
```